# Outdated processor microcode

Tags: apt, updates, microcode

So after running `apt update ; apt upgrade` a while ago, I ran upon the following message:

[image: Outdated procesor microcode warning]

But I keep seeing this message after updating some softwares even if I reboot. My computer seems to work fine but I have no idea why I still see this message. Anybody knows what that means?

Answer (score 2):

This means that, for some reason, the "intel-microcode" package is not being able to update the microcode on your computer.

If you're in an ASUS (and only ASUS) machine, *update the firmware/BIOS/UEFI*.  Some of their models are set up in such a weird way that requires a firmware update to update microcode, where everyone else just needs the microcode update.

In any other case, please ensure you have the "intel-microcode" package installed, and that its version starts with 3.20190618 (or higher).

If intel-microcode's version is older than 20190618, you need a newer version of the package -- but this is strange, it would likely mean you're using an unsupported version of Ubuntu, *or* that you disabled security updates since Ubuntu has updated intel-microcode on every supported branch recently to the 3.20190618* release.

Last, try to recall if you have not disabled microcode updates ("dis_ucode_ldr" parameter on the bootloader) for some reason -- the system won't do this, so if you did not do it, then this is not the problem.

Comment: When I try: 'apt install intel-microcode' it tell me I: 'intel-microcode is already the newest version (3.20190618.0ubuntu0.18.04.1).' And I did not touch any bootloader parameters (unless the previous user of my PC or IT did). But since this started to happen while I was using this PC I doubt it is the case.

Answer (score 0):

has mentioned here (https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/install-update-intel-microcode-firmware-linux/) you have to update the microcode for your CPU. The issue is Intel decided to "stop the distribution" as you could see with the [result of this research](https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/search.html#q=microcode%20linux&t=Products)